# Automatically saving interactive graph in R to a specified location as a .html file

Tags: r

I am using **threejs** library in R.

```
  library(threejs)
  z <- seq(-10, 10, 0.01)
  x <- cos(z)
  y <- sin(z)
scatterplot3js(x,y,z, color=rainbow(length(z)))
```

I need to save the interactive plot created by above commands as a.html file in a specified folder without using the drop down (in Rstudio) under viwer -> export  which "save as web page".

Is there any R code for this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using `htmlwidgets` package you can do...

```
library(htmlwidgets)

dir.create("Z:\\new folder")

saveWidget(scatterplot3js(x,y,z, color=rainbow(length(z))), 
           file="Z:\\new folder\\scatterplot.html")
```

Comment: thank you so much! I can accept your answer in 7 minutes :P

Comment: If I try to save in some new folder which I have not created , it is throwing an error. Is there any way to fix this issue?

`saveWidget(scatterplot3js(x,y,z, color=rainbow(length(z))), file="D:/temp1/scatterplot.html")
Error in setwd(dir) : cannot change working directory`